# How to hide single labels on a symfony form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, label

I am creating a very custom form on a symfony project and currently I have something like this:

```
foreach ($foo as $c) {
        $fields['crit_v_'.$c->getId()]=new sfWidgetFormInput(array('label'=>''));
        $fields['crit_m_'.$c->getId()]=new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array('label'=>__($c->getName(),array(),'messages')));
    }
```

As you can see I have 2 inputs foreach element, but I only want to have a label for the second one. Setting the label for the first one to `null` or to `''` does not make symfony to not render this label and displays the default text for this label. (This  means the for input is labeled  `crit_v_xx`.)
Is there any simple way to hide specific form labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

I make a seperate template file called `_form.php` which looked like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('evaluation_submit')?>" method="post">
<?php echo $form['id']?>
<div> <!-- with label -->
    <?php echo $form['foo']->renderLabel() ?>
    <?php echo $form['foo']->renderError() ?>
    <?php echo $form['foo'] ?>
</div>
<div> <!-- without label -->
    <?php echo $form['bar']->renderError() ?>
    <?php echo $form['bar'] ?>
</div>
```

In the main template for this action I included the form like this:

```
<?php include_partial('form', array('form' => $form)) ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you set the label to false then symfony will not render the `<label>` tags at all. False behaves differently then null or ''

```
$your_form->widgetSchema->setLabel('the_field_id', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just disable it in the generator.yml

```
filter:
  fields:
    name: { label: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the label of a single field in a symfony form as blank:

```
$your_form->widgetSchema->setLabel('the_field_id', ' ');
```

It will render the `<label>` tags, but with a blank space inside, so they won't output anything on the browser

Comment: Sorry I meant to type a blank space, if you put an empty string it will not work (as you already know). this way, it will render the <label> tags, but with a blank space inside, so they won't output anything on the browser. Its a little questionable but it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom row format that defines how the fields will be rendered (if you are not using a custom template anyway). I found it in this [forum thread](http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/82827/).

A good solution might be overriding the `formatRow` method:

```
public function formatRow($label, $field, $errors = array(), $help = '', $hiddenFields = null)
{
    if(strip_tags($label) == '__UNSET__')
    {
        return strtr($this->getRowFormat(), array(
            '%label%'         => null,
            '%field%'         => $field,
            '%error%'         => $this->formatErrorsForRow($errors),
            '%help%'          => $this->formatHelp($help),
            '%hidden_fields%' => is_null($hiddenFields) ? '%hidden_fields%' : $hiddenFields,
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        return strtr($this->getRowFormat(), array(
            '%label%'         => $label,
            '%field%'         => $field,
            '%error%'         => $this->formatErrorsForRow($errors),
            '%help%'          => $this->formatHelp($help),
            '%hidden_fields%' => is_null($hiddenFields) ? '%hidden_fields%' : $hiddenFields,
        ));
    }
}
```

Then you set `__UNSET__` as label for those fields that should not have their label rendered.

Or you even use a custom row format depending on the label name to prevent outputting the enclosing tag of the label.
A row format would look like this `<div >%field%%help%%error%%hidden_fields%</div>` and would pass this instead of `$this->getRowFormat()`.